# ghost key and unpressable keys issue on android HTC desire Z

Tags: htc-desire, hardware, screen, troubleshooting

On my screen the area where the letters "w e r" and "a s d" seems to press itself on its own, to a point most of my apps are inaccessible. If I have to write a text message or dial a number, I have to be really creative to achieve that desired goal. Also, the letters "e" and "d" are not pressable, as in when I press them, I get any of the letters surrounding it but not that specific one.

I cleaned my screen, recalibrated my screen, and reconfigured my keyboard, and have tried to google the issue. Are there any fixes or workarounds?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault with the touchscreen capacitor in not "understanding" the touches and end result of "ghost key" - Was it dropped or exposed to water at some stage?

Comment: Not really water, but once or twice it was held up in the rain, but i usually wipe it up as fast as I can

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP's comment above, well, *once or twice*, meaning, yes it was exposed to water!

Rain **is** water. Could have gone in between the bezel of the handset or moisture residue got built up.

Get it checked out hardware wise... would not be surprised if the moisture build up is interfering with the touchscreen's recognition of touch.